# Running SparkR process is giving error in Mac OS X

Tags: r

I have installed SparkR in Mac OS X. (Please note i have not installed Spark or Scala). I was able to initiate SparkR , how ever i get below error while doing operations -

```
> data <- textFile(sc, "README.md")  
> count(data)
15/03/27 19:53:12 INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
Error in .jcall(getJRDD(rdd), "Ljava/util/List;", "collect") : 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in
stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:228)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:431)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:527)
    sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
```

Any help will be appreciated. I am using AMPLAB SparkR.
http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/5/exercises/sparkr.html

Comment: I don't see how you expect SparkR to work without Spark. You cannot dive into pool without knowing how to swim.

Comment: Good point. I probably overlooked any prerequisite that spark needs to be installed. The SparkR does allows to initiates a spark context. If it requires to install spark it should not allow to create a spark context.